# In Django, how to display times with lowercase am/pm in templates?

Tags: django, django-templates

Django's [date/time formats](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date) have a code for displaying the am/pm part of times as either:

```
a.m.
```

or

```
AM
```

but not as:

```
am
```

i.e. lowercase without periods.

How do you render times with lowercase am/pm?

NOTE: I thought of the answer while typing in this question, so I figured instead of scrapping it I'd share my answer in case it's helpful to someone else.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use the `lower` template tag with the `time` formatting tag, e.g.

```
{{object.time|time:"g:iA"|lower}}
```

renders as

```
12:30pm
```

compared to

```
{{object.time|time:"g:iA"}}
```

which renders as

```
12:30PM
```

Note simply using the `lower` filter on a time object without the explicit `time` format filter doesn't work. But you can use the default time format, e.g.

```
{{object.time|time|lower}}
```